# Windows: script/program for USB key that opens a console, and sets the path and the working directory

Tags: batch-file, console, terminal, dos, usb-drive

The goal behind this question is to create a portable Windows script/program that would help users *run (console) programs directly from a USB key* (not necessarily through autorun, though).  The script/program would thus do the following *when double clicked on*:

- Launch a console (`cmd` would do) and give a DOS command prompt,
- Have the current directory set to a specific directory `WorkingDir` on the USB key (which contains various [Python] programs),
- Set the path so that the user can run a command (python.exe) found in another USB key directory (so that the user can launch various Python programs found in `WorkingDir`).

The whole thing is based on [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/), which is on the USB key.  I would also like to be able to simply put the contents of the key on a hard drive and use it from there.

I tried to write a file that contains commands like:

```
PATH=..\"Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App":%PATH%
cd WorkingDir
cmd
```

but I'm not sure how to call it so that Windows runs it (and I was therefore not able to see whether these command would work).

I don't know much about DOS and Windows, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in windows you use ; for separating paths :) And you shouldn't use .. like that. You can use %CD% to get current directory and then navigate from it. And don't use quotes. Also, you could put @ before any command that you don't wish to be echoed to the console.

You can put this into run.bat (this should work :P):

```
@PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\..\Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App
@cd WorkingDir
@cmd
```

And then just double click it and it will open commmand prompt just as you want it. Or maybe you can add autorun.inf file to open it automatically.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to call the script run.bat, but double clicking on it launches a text editor.  Is there a way of making the script clickable?

Comment: PS: it appears that the script is actually called run.bat.txt, but that Windows Vista shows it like run.bat.  I found a way of renaming it and things now work.

Comment: Shouldn't %PATH% be put at the *end* of the new path instead of at the beginning?  in fact, I would like programs (including Python) that are installed on the key to be executed in priority.

Comment: Yeah, you can put it in the beginning, my mistake ;)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, as I was not sure how Windows handles path priority.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was of any help ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create two files:

**autorun.inf**

```
[autorun]
open=cmd.exe "Python Console" /k autorun.cmd
action=Open Python Console...
```

**autorun.cmd**

```
@Echo Off
CD %~d0\WorkingDir
Path %Path%;%~d0\Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App
```

The phrase `%~d0` represents the drive the command file resides, namely the flash drive's letter (E:).

Now, I encountered two slight hiccups.  My USB drive had a hidden, system, readonly autorun.inf file on it already.  I had to unprotect it with the following command before I could edit it.

```
Attrib autorun.inf -r -s -h
```

My second hiccup, is that Windows 7 won't autorun from a USB drive.  You have to right-click the drive in Explorer and select "Run Python Console..."

Comment: I may be missing something, but if it is supposed to be a *Python* console then shouldn't the script start a *Python* console?

Comment: @Andriy M: users actually need a DOS shell, so that they can launch various Python programs from there.  I edited the question to make this completely explicit, thanks.  As a side note: Portable Python already offers scripts that launch a Python shell.